# Transitivity relationship: What is x.equals(z) when x.equals(y) is false and y.equals(z) is true

Tags: java, logic, equals, equality

Assuming equals() is transitive;
I understand that if x and y, have a bilateral agreement of  being equal, then  one of them, say y, does not enter into an agreement with a third class z on its own. *But if we have a situation where x.equals(y) = false (still  transitive) then what should this bilateral agreement with z be?*

Comment: Wait a minute. If x is different from y, what can the relation between y and z be ?
I guess the question would have been more interesting if x.equals(y)==true.

Comment: So are `x`, `y` and `z` classes or instances? If so, you should use upper-case letters, or it will become confusing.

Answer (score 6):

If the `equals` method is correctly implemented, as demanded by the javadoc of Object:

> > - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
> > - **It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true**.
> > - **It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true**.
> > - It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
> > - For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

we can infer that x.equals(z) must be false.

Prove, if `equals()` is transitive and symmetric, x.equals(y) is false and y.equals(z) is true:

1) assuming x.equals(z) is true;
2) z.equals(y) is true  (symmetry);
1+2) x.equals(y) is true  (transitive 1 and 2)

but x.equals(y) is given as false, so number 1 or number 2 must be wrong, that is, x.equals(z) is false or the function is not symmetric.

But if `equals()` is not implemented to be symmetric, you can't say anything about the result x.equals(z) (see other answers; my comment on @Stephen C answer)

Answer (score 2):

Well:

```
x ≢ y
y ≡ z
```

since equals() is transitive, you can replace y with z:

```
x ≢ z
```

Therefore, x.equals(z) is false.

Edit: It just comes down to boolean logic, which is also transitive.

Comment: As you may or may not know, `x == y` and `x.equals(y)` are not equivalent in Java. The question is about the `equals(Object)` method, so in order to avoid confusion I wouldn't use the `==` operator in an answer, even as a shorthand notation for `equals(Object)`.

Comment: I just used `==` and `!=` because they are the standard logic operators, and the question was whether `x` equaled to `z`. It doesn't really matter how equals() is implemented, since the fundamental rules are the same as for boolean logic.

Comment: In that case I would use `≡` and `≢`, or `⇔` and `⇎`.  Maybe it's just me, but in the Java context it's very misleading to use `==` and `equals` interchangeably.  Note: I'm not saying that your answer is wrong, but the answer may be confusing to novice Java programmers reading it.

Comment: I'd also prefer those symbols, it's just that I didn't know how to type them. I'll guess I'll update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

@Colin HEBERT has answered this.  I'd just like to point out a possible source of the OP's confusion.

There are actually two different relations here:

- the EQ relation (i.e. `x.equals(y) == true`) is transitive.
- the NE relation (i.e. `x.equals(y) == false`) is NOT transitive.

Furthermore, the transitivity property only allows you to reason about to chains involving one relation; i.e. `x EQ y && y EQ Z implies x EQ Z`.  The question tries to use transitivity to reason about `x NE y && y EQ z` ... and it doesn't apply to that case.

Comment: just an example: using "is greater than" which also is transitive: `A > B` and `B > C` implies in `A > C`. But if we have `A <= B` and `B > C` we can NOT say `A <= C` or `A > C`, both are possible.

Answer (score 0):

There can be only two main scenarii:

1. x.equals(y)

   ```
   y.equals(x)
   if x.equals(z) then y.equals(z), z.equals(x), z.equals(y)
   if !x.equals(z) then !y.equals(z), !z.equals(x), !z.equals(y)
   ```
2. !x.equals(y)

   ```
   !y.equals(x)
   if x.equals(z) then !y.equals(z), z.equals(x), !z.equals(y)
   if !x.equals(z) then !z.equals(x) // you can't know the rest for sure
   ```

Answer (score 0):

TO @Colin HEBERT: 
The assumption here is that equals() method does abide by the contract of  equivalence relation.
So for objects x and y if x.equals(y) returns false then y.equals(x) is also false. This is the symmetric relationship between them. Now  for transitivity, if we have another object z  and y.equals(z) is true. What should x.equals(z)  return in context of this equivalence relation where x.equals(y) and y.equals(x) return false, and why?